# Hadoop and map-reduce on multicore machines

Tags: hadoop, multicore

I have read a lot about Hadoop and Map-Reduce running on clusters of machines. Does some one know if the Apache distribution can be run on an SMP with several cores. In particular, can multiple Map-Reduce processes be run on the same machine. The scheduler will take care of spreading them across multiple cores. Thanks. - KG

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You have multiple map and reduce slots in each machine which are determined by the RAM and CPU (each JVM instance needs 1GB by default so a 8GB machine with 16 cores should still have 7 task slots)

from [hadoop wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_see_a_maximum_of_2_maps.2BAC8-reduces_spawned_concurrently_on_each_TaskTracker.2C_how_do_I_increase_that.3F)

> Use the configuration knob: mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and
>   mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum to control the number of
>   maps/reduces spawned simultaneously on a TaskTracker. By default, it
>   is set to 2, hence one sees a maximum of 2 maps and 2 reduces at a
>   given instance on a TaskTracker.
>
> You can set those on a per-tasktracker basis to accurately reflect
>   your hardware (i.e. set those to higher nos. on a beefier tasktracker
>   etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use those lightweight MapReduce frameworks for multicore computers.

For example

LeoTask: A lightweight, productive, and reliable mapreduce framework for multicore computers

https://github.com/mleoking/LeoTask

Answer (score 0):

For Apache Hadoop 2.7.3, my experience has been that enabling YARN will also enable multi-core support. Here is a simple guide for enabling YARN on a single node:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_a_Single_Node

The default configuration seems to work pretty well. If you want to tune your core usage, then perhaps look into setting 'yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores' and 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores' within yarn-site.xml (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Also, see here for instructions on how to configure a simple Hadoop sandbox with multicore support: https://bitbucket.org/aperezrathke/hadoop-aee