# Run Map-Reduce application on multiple core on the same machine

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to run map reduce tasks on a single machine and I want to use all the cores of my machine. Which is the best approach? If I install hadoop in pseudo distributed mode it is possible to use all the cores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the properties **mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum** and **mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum** to increase the number of Mappers/Reducers spawned simultaneously on a TaskTracker as per your hardware specs. By default, it is set to 2, hence a maximum of 2 maps and 2 reduces will run at a given instance. But, one thing to keep in mind is that if your input is very small then framework will decide it's not worth parallelizing the execution. In such a case you need to handle it by tweaking the default split size through **mapred.max.split.size**.

Having said that, I, based on my personal experience, have noticed that MR jobs are normally I/O(perhaps memory, sometimes) bound. So, CPU does not really become a bottleneck under normal circumstances. As a result you might find it difficult to fully utilize all the cores on one machine at a time for a job.

I would suggest to devise some strategy to decide the proper number of Mappers/Reducers to efficiently carry out the processing to make sure that you are properly utilizing the CPU since Mappers/Reducers take up slots on each node. One approach could be to take the **number of cores**, multiply it by **.75** and then set the number of Mappers and Reducers as per your needs. **For example**, you have **12 physical cores or 24 virtual cores**, then you could have **24*.75 = 18** slots. Now based on your needs you can decide whether to use **9Mappers+9Reducers** or **12Mappers+6Reducers** or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reposting my answer from this question: [Hadoop and map-reduce on multicore machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657473/hadoop-and-map-reduce-on-multicore-machines/)

For Apache Hadoop 2.7.3, my experience has been that enabling YARN will also enable multi-core support. Here is a simple guide for enabling YARN on a single node:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_a_Single_Node

The default configuration seems to work pretty well. If you want to tune your core usage, then perhaps look into setting 'yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores' and 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores' within yarn-site.xml (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Also, see here for instructions on how to configure a simple Hadoop sandbox with multicore support: https://bitbucket.org/aperezrathke/hadoop-aee